# What is difference between Gradient Descent and Grid Search in Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, grid-search

Hyperparameter Tuning use two techniques like **Grid Search** or Random Search.
**Gradient Descent** is mostly used to minimize the Loss function.

Here query is in when we will use Grid Search and Gradient descent.

Answer (score 4):

- Gradient Descent is used to optimize the model meaning its weights and biases to minimize the loss. It tries to reach to minima of the loss function and their generalise the model to a good extent. It optimizes the model based on the hyperparameters given to it.
  For example, the learning rate is used like

  W = W - ( learning_rate * gradient )

Here, the hyperparameter of learning rate affects W which are the weights.

- In order to choose a better value of a hyperparameter, GridSearch and RandomSearch algorithms are used. Hyperparameters are constant during training but need to be fine tuned so that the model converges at something good.

**Gradient Descent optimizes the model based on hyperparameters. Whereas in order to fine tune the hyperparameters, GridSearch and RandomSearch are used.**

Gradient descent is used for the optimization of the model ( weights and biases ) 
Hyperparameter Tuning algorithms fine tune hyperparameter which affect the gradient descent.
 The usage could be followed in this way.

1. Train the model on some chosen hyperparameters.
2. Evaluate the model for its loss and accuracy.
3. Run hyperparameter tuning to get better values for hyperparameters.
4. Train the model again with updated hyperparameters.
5. Follow this routine until the model reaches a considerable high accuracy and less loss.

Comment: how can i implement grid seach on batch gradient descent to fine tune the step size parameter.i could not find a python module for batch gradient descent like linear regression and am finding difficulty to get a perfect value of the hyperparameter